# Status of the Junta Problem (soft question)

Tags: soft-question, machine-learning, boolean-functions, pac-learning

Does the learning theory community in general believe that juntas can be learned in polynomial time?

The naive algorithm works in quasi-polynomial time. MOS's paper shows how to solve the junta problem in nearly O(n^(2logn/3)) time, which as far as I can tell is the best upper bound today.

Do more than 50% of experts believe that the Junta problem IS solvable in polynomial time?

Thanks.

Comment: You’re asking about Majority of experts, and your question can be generalized to k-juntas.

Comment: I would say, people has enough belief in its hardness to base lower bounds (conditional) on it: http://proceedings.mlr.press/v19/feldman11a.html (Theorem 9)